# How to disable gesture highlight animation on onGesturePerformed?

Tags: android, gesture, gestures, android-gesture

I was doing similar gesture detection from vogella tutorial [here.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html)

My MainActivity is:

```
        package com.example.gesturesaveopendocs;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.gesture.Gesture;
    import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
    import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
    import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
    import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
    import android.gesture.Prediction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
            OnGesturePerformedListener {

        GestureLibrary gesture_library;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            gesture_library = GestureLibraries
                    .fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
            if (!gesture_library.load()) {
                finish();
            }

            GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
            gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        }

        public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
            ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gesture_library.recognize(gesture);

            if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
                String result = predictions.get(0).name;

                if ("open".equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Opening the document", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } else if ("save".equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Saving the document", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

I would like to disable the highlight replication (yellow animation) from my finger gestures on the screen. Since I would only need the gesture functionality in my app without the highlight animation showing up everytime I swipe.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can turn this off, via setGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) or setUncertainGestureColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) on the GestureOverlayView.

Comment: Okay so I tried this but when I started to make a gesture, the highlight still shows up at the very slight moment. Then I found this `gestures.setGestureVisible(false);` so this made the gesture animation invisible. Thanks though for the input. Cheers!